# Twilio nested play in gather

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using twilio for automated outbound call. I am trying to play an audio file and simultaneously gather input from user. And when user gives input stop that audio file and gather action must be called.
What I have done is :

```
gather = Gather(input='speech dtmf',speechTimeout=2,numDigits=1, action="gatherResponse/{}".format(call_id), method='POST')
response.play("https://any_audio_url.mp3")
response.append(gather)
```

This code just plays the audio file, gather action is not called.

Comment: A brief glance at the documentation makes it seem gather is always used prior to playing something so as to "gather" information necessary for a proper response to be played?

Comment: gather is working fine if i am using response.say but with response.play it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I would nest the [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) within the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) to achieve what you describe. Try your code this way around (note, I'm using `gather.play`):

```
gather = Gather(input='speech dtmf',speechTimeout=2,numDigits=1, action="gatherResponse/{}".format(call_id), method='POST')
gather.play("https://any_audio_url.mp3")
response.append(gather)
```

Check the [examples in the documentation for more detail](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather?code-sample=code-gather-speech-or-dtmf-with-nested-say&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x).